# ruby rackup: is it possible to programatically add a mapping from within another mapping?

Tags: ruby, web-services, webserver, rack

I have a .ru file and can set up mappings without issue ( the 'register' mapping below ).

However I want services to be able to register themselves by hitting a url so I want to be able to add new mappings on the fly from within others mappings.

The below code does *not* work though.  What am I doing wrong and is this possible?

Thanks!

```
map '/register' do
  run Proc.new { |env|
    # inside of register i want to add another mapping.
    # obviously 'bar' would be a value read out of env
    map '/bar' do
      run Proc.new{ |env| ['200', { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' },'bar' }
    end

    [ '200', {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, "registered"]
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to add routes after-the-fact using `map`. One alternative is to use [Rack::URLMap](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/URLMap) to define your app. You'll need to maintain your own list of registered routes (as a hash) and call `Rack::URLMap#remap` every time you add a new route to the hash:

```
url_map = Rack::URLMap.new
routes = {
  "/register" => lambda do |env|
    routes["/bar"] = lambda do |env|
      [ "200", {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["bar"] ]
    end

    url_map.remap(routes)

    [ "200", {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["registered"] ]
  end
}

url_map.remap(routes)
run url_map
```

Note that you could do with with just the hash, but URLMap provides some nice conveniences, including 404 handling. It's actually a really nice little class and [worth reading](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/25a549883b85fb33970b4a1530a365c0c9e51f95/lib/rack/urlmap.rb) if you have five minutes to spare.

If you were so inclined, you could turn this into a tidy little class:

```
class Application
  def initialize
    @routes = {}
    @url_map = Rack::URLMap.new

    register_route "/register" do |env|
      # When "/register" is requested, register the new route "/bar"
      register_route "/bar" do |env|
        [ 200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["bar"] ]
      end
      [ 200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["registered"] ]
    end
  end

  def call(env)
    @url_map.call(env)
  end

  private
  def register_route(path, &block)
    @routes[path] = block
    @url_map.remap(@routes)
  end
end

run Application.new
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://rack.github.io/, "To use Rack, provide an "app": an object that responds to the call method, taking the environment hash as a parameter, and returning an Array with three elements:

- The HTTP response code
- A Hash of headers
- The response body, which must respond to `each`"

Your third element will not respond to `each`. Maybe wrap it in an array?

Comment: you are correct that "registered" and "bar" need to be in an array but this still didn't get 'bar' registerd